# $_GET['productid'] gives Undefined even though my url gives the id

Tags: javascript, php, html, get

He I'm trying to convert my Javascript var to a php var. I currently use the window.location.href methode but it keeps giving this error

```
function getId() {
    var url = '#?';
    var query = 'productid=' + productid;
    window.location.href = url + query;
            }
//on buttonclick sends the id to the same page

var_dump($_GET['productid']); //Gives the undefined

$id = $_GET['productid'];
var_dump($id) //Gives undefined aswell
```

error

[image]

link

[image]

Comment: take out the #.  Fragments come after parameters.

Comment: Thanks thought I needed it to stay on the page like I do with Submits

Comment: Just remember that nothing after `#` gets sent to the server, it's used only by the client.